# Clarification on magnets URI

Tags: seeding, magnet-uri

I did a bit of research around magnets and wanted to make some. Magnet should only be a hash of a file that will be found on DHT nodes to be downloaded afterward.

What I don't understand is, if it was that simple, how is it that I'm unable to seed a magnet directly created without tracker right away ?

As I had understood it, my torrent client should know about the DHT nodes and share if anyboidy requested the good hash. But it does not seem to work that way.

So, I don't know what is the reality now.

> Is a magnets an alias to another torrent only, and can't work on their own ?
>   Does a magnet require a tracker specified to work ?
>   Can I generate a magnet link in one commandline ? (my project was all about that first using rhash)